# Chome with classic Menu Bar

Tags: chrome, gui, menu

I am looking for an extension or a special built of Google Chrome providing the traditional Menu Bar with the usual "File, Edit,..." entries:

[image: traditional menu bar]
<sup>Firefox with traditional menu bar</sup>

I'd like have this mainly for better consistency with the other desktop apps and i don't mind wasting ~20px out of 1080px to display a static menu.

Answer (score 1):

The recently-released [Vivaldi browser has an "Horizontal Main Menu" option](https://help.vivaldi.com/article/menu/).
The menu does not have the native look'n'feel, but it is still better than the usual chrome button IMO.

The browser also has a traditional status bar and it is compatible with most Chrome extensions.

The only problem are the unmovable extension buttons, hopefully they will be fixed in the next updates...

Comment: How do you like that browser?

Comment: It's still in beta releases, but in the end it's just a Chrome clone with a more colorful interface.